# Casbah (Scala) Generating a query statement with nested conditions ($OR $AND)

Tags: mongodb, scala, conditional-statements, querydsl, casbah

Given items: `[{ prop1 : "a", prop2 : "b" , prop3, "c",....},....]`
and patterns:`[{ prop1 : "a", prop2 : "Any"},...]`

I want to create a query to find  all patterns that match the given items.

The resulting query is of form:

```
((A or B or C) AND (D or E or F) AND (G or H or J))
or
((A or B or C) AND (D or E or F) AND (G or H or J))
or
((A or B or C) AND (D or E or F) AND (G or H or J))
....
```

I've tried to build a DSL-form , but I get an ambiguous implicit error on the init:

Can this notation be used? Or how could I implement this with DBObject.Builder or MongoDbObjects?

Thanks,
Eli

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports._

/* test data */
val thing1 = Map[String,String]("thing_type" -> "PC", "os"-> "Windows", "vendor"-> "lenova")
val thing2 = Map[String,String]("thing_type" -> "Tablet", "os"-> "iOS", "vendor"-> "Apple")
"

val things_list = List(thing1, thing2)
/* end test data */

val atts_for_search = List("thing_type", "os", "vendor" )
var pattern_query = $or()                      // *causes a compilation error
things_list.foreach ( thing => {
    var att_and_list = $and()               // *causes a compilation error
    atts_for_search.foreach ( att => {
          att_and_list ++= $or(att $eq thing(att),att $exists false,att $eq "Any")

    }) // foreach attribute
    pattern_query  ++= att_and_list
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$or` and `$and` parts of the dsl require a traversable and can't initiated without one - hence the compile error.

If you can just delay the creation of the `$and` and `$or` parts of the query until you have built the traversable it works:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports._

/* test data */
val thing1 = Map[String,String]("thing_type" -> "PC", "os"-> "Windows", "vendor"-> "lenova")
val thing2 = Map[String,String]("thing_type" -> "Tablet", "os"-> "iOS", "vendor"-> "Apple")
val things_list = List(thing1, thing2)
/* end test data */

val atts_for_search = List("thing_type", "os", "vendor" )
val ors = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[DBObject]()
things_list.foreach ( thing => {
    var ands = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[DBObject]()
    atts_for_search.foreach ( att => {
          ands += $or(att $eq thing(att),att $exists false,att $eq "Any")

    }) // foreach attribute
    ands  += $and(ands)
})
val pattern_query = $or(ors)
```

This returns the following output:

```
{"$or": [{ "$and": [{ "$or": [ { "thing_type" : "PC"} , { "thing_type" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "thing_type" : "Any"}]} , 
                    { "$or": [ { "os" : "Windows"} , { "os" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "os" : "Any"}]} , 
                    { "$or": [ { "vendor" : "lenova"} , { "vendor" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "vendor" : "Any"}]}]} , 
         { "$and": [{ "$or": [ { "thing_type" : "Tablet"} , { "thing_type" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "thing_type" : "Any"}]} , 
                    { "$or": [ { "os" : "iOS"} , { "os" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "os" : "Any"}]} , 
                    { "$or": [ { "vendor" : "Apple"} , { "vendor" : { "$exists" : false}} , { "vendor" : "Any"}]}]}]}
```